# Disable file upload control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

How can i disable or enable File upload control of .NET framework using Javascript??

Does any one have idea, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function EnableDisable(rbl) {
        var rb = rbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
        document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < rb.length; i++) {
            if (rb[i].value == 1 && rb[i].checked) {
                document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>



<form runat = "server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" onclick = "EnableDisable(this)">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Yes" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "No" Value = "2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" disabled = "disabled"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById(FileUploadControlID).disabled = true;
```